# Ubuntu 20.04 randomly freezes on my Lenovo Thinkpad L15 Gen2

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm not sure why but the gnome session of the computer randomly freezes,only the mouse keeps working.

Also tried to change to another terminal with `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F3`, which works fine, but not been able to restart the desktop.

Versions:

- Ubuntu is 20.04
- Gnome-shell 3.36

This is the last journal data I captured, but different freezes leaves different logs:

```
ago 26 14:25:01 laptop1 CRON[22482]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ago 26 14:25:01 laptop1 CRON[22483]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
ago 26 14:25:01 laptop1 CRON[22482]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
ago 26 14:25:27 laptop1 filebeat[7354]: 2021-08-26T14:25:27.246-0300        INFO        [monitoring]        log/log.go:145        Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":>
ago 26 14:25:38 laptop1 wpa_supplicant[1021]: wlp9s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
ago 26 14:25:57 laptop1 filebeat[7354]: 2021-08-26T14:25:57.247-0300        INFO        [monitoring]        log/log.go:145        Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":>
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "29"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "30"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "31"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event8  - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "32"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "33"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "34"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event6  - TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "35"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event7  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "87"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event16 - Kingston HyperX Cloud Stinger Core (Wireless) – PS Consumer Control: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "72"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "72"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event14 - Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (**) Option "fd" "93"
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) event15 - Logitech Wireless Mouse: device removed
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:79
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:78
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:80
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
ago 26 14:26:42 laptop1 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1233]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to Gnome in those logs. Are you using any extensions? The majority of the time, when something goes wrong with Gnome, it's an extension misbehaving. Try disabling all extensions and see if you still experience freezes. Can you access `ALT+F2` and type `r` to restart gnome?

Comment: `alt` + `F2` is not working, only thing I can do is to open a different terminal and type some commands, but when doing `sudo` then it also dies.

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: No swap issues, plenty of free RAM when this fails. I'll add an edit with a better snapshot of the journal